# Get input value and use it with variable with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, weather-api

I have an input field with id="to" which is empty and when user types in something, and press the submit, it should change the location attribute in the script below. But, nothing happens.

```
oldvalue = document.getElementById("to").value;
var newvalue;
var inputBox = document.getElementById("to");
inputBox.onchange = function(){
    newvalue = document.getElementById("to").value;
    oldvalue = newvalue;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: oldvalue,
    unit: 'c',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
      html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
      html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
});
```

HTML INPUT

```
<div class="input-group add-on">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="to: " id="to">                
<button id='tobtn' class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>               
</div>
```

Comment: Does page reloads after submit?

Comment: Why do you think it should change the location? The function is not called after an `onchange`. You just set a new `oldvalue`.

Comment: @mpavlovic89 So the page reloads and your page is reset to the initial state. No wonder nothing happens.

Comment: I am not sure I am following you. I understand there is a problem, but I cannot see the solution.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work this way? I mean, similar way?

Comment: could you also show the HTML and the JS part where you submit?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

*JavaScript:*

```
oldvalue = document.getElementById("to").value;
var newvalue;
var inputBox = document.getElementById("to");
inputBox.onchange = function(){
    newvalue = document.getElementById("to").value;
    oldvalue = newvalue;
};

var loadWeather = function(location) {
    $.simpleWeather({
       location: location,
       unit: 'c',
       success: function(weather) {
           html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i>  '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
           html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
           html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
           $("#weather").html(html);
       },
       error: function(error) {
           $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
       }
   });
}

var refreshWeather = function(){
    loadWeather(oldvalue);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   loadWeather(oldvalue);
});
```

*HTML:*

```
<div class="input-group add-on">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="to: " id="to">                
    <button id='tobtn' class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="refreshWeather();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>               
</div>
```

I change the submit button for a normal button because I think you don't need to call to the server in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is that your HTML button is set to type "submit". It appears like you want to do things client-side (using JavaScript) when the user presses the button instead of submitting data to a server-side component.

Try setting the type to "button" instead. Bind a click event to the button and do your $.simpleWeather call in the event handler. This should probably fix you up.

EDIT: To actually bind javascript to your button, one thing you can do is this:

```
<button onclick="refreshWeather()">Submit</button>
```

Then just put your $.simpleWeather code in a function by that name